# Showing marker symbol even when no value in field using QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, fields-attributes, markers

In QGIS, I have been learning a few expressions to style my trail maps but still know little and am stumped on what to use to filter my symbol data.

I am showing Parking locations on my map. I use a marker symbol as a background element, so I can do callouts. I created a data field and added values to display beside this symbol a number that references a list of parking addresses in the book's text.

All good except if the field has no number to display, it is `NULL`, it does not display my marker symbol. I need to filter this, so it does show even when there is no value in the field.

Comment: What kind of symbology did u use for the layer ? The Marker **should appear** even if your data field is null unless u used a **rule-based** symbology taking that case in account.

Answer (score 1):

So ... you are using a **rule-based symbology**.

I think you could try the following *(even if we don't see the rules you use)* :

Instead of **"PLot"** *only* try to label your sites with `coalesce("PLot",'')` that should enable you to handle NULL cases.

A second possibility could be to elaborate the rules of your symbology a bit more in order to exclude these NULL cases. (that means test your values using **IF** conditions)

Comment: Coalesce condition did not do it. The User Guide mentions  "Returns the first non-NULL value from the expression list." So it seems it needs to see a value instead of NULL to work.

Comment: That's the aim of the expression ... if your PLot data is NULL then return a blank space ... i don't see the use of manually replacing your data ... are u able to share your project and some or all of your data ? at least your .qgs file ?

Answer (score 1):

Modify the data in PLot to contain a space instead of a Null. Then the problem may go away. Or use a ? to indicate to the viewer that the number of the lot is unknown. That may be important. Features without attributes are usually not as good as features with attributes.

Comment: In the end, I could not sort out how to filter my attributeless Parking icons to display. I agree they should ALL have a reference attribute to aid the map user in finding the addresses listed in my text. So I  am moving on and may yet solve this some other day. For now, I can tailor my maps to work.

Comment: saying "now my map works" without indicating the way u solved it is all but useful on this kind of help site ..

Comment: Well as wingnut had eluded perhaps I should not seek to show Features (my Parking Icons) with no reference numbers. And I agree they all should have a # to reference my list of street addresses listed in my text. So this was a solution for me, as I avoided the posted issue, granted not a solution to the problem. (Sorry, I am on a tight deadline and I need to move forward on this project.)